# Getting value from slider to display on a different screen (python, kivy)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to display the value of a slider on a different screen. i have tried this(below code) but for some reason, the value doesn't seem to show up. the code runs fine but no value is returned. Thanks for your help :) Cheers.

temperature screen

[image]

here is a snippet of the python code:

```
class Thermostat(Screen):
label = StringProperty()
    def display(self):
        tempVal = self.label 
        return str(tempVal)
```

and the kv files:

```
<Thermostat>:
name: "thermostat"
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    cols: 2

    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: "11sp"
        text: "INSIDE: " + root.display()

    Label:
        text: "More Info"
        font_size: "11sp"
```

kv file 2:This screen holds the true value from the slider, i am trying to pass that value to the Thermostat screen.

```
<Temperature>:
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '48dp'
    cols: 3

    Label:
        text: 'THERMOSTAT'

    Slider:
        id: temp
        min: 40
        max: 100
        value: 1
        step: 1
        on_value: app.root.get_screen('thermostat').label = str('{}'.format(temp.value))    

    Label:
        id: slide_val
        text: '{}'.format(temp.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root.display` is only called once, at the beginning of the program. For it to work well, every time you change the value of the slider `root.display` should be called.

However, it is very simple to do this using propertis in kv languaje:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder



Builder.load_string('''

<Manager>:
    id: manager
    Thermostat:
        id: thermostat
        name: 'thermostat'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
        temp: temperature.temp                    #<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Temperature:
        id: temperature
        name: 'temperature'
        manager: 'screen_manager'


<Thermostat>:
    temp: 0                                       #<<<<<<<<<<<<
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        cols: 3

        Label:
            id: label
            font_size: "11sp"
            text: "INSIDE: {}".format(root.temp)  #<<<<<<<<<<<<

        Label:
            text: "More Info"
            font_size: "11sp"

        Button:
            text: ">"
            on_release: app.root.current= "temperature"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 30



<Temperature>:
    temp: temp_slider.value                              #<<<<<<<<<<<<
    BoxLayout:
        cols: 4

        Button:
            text: "<"
            on_press: app.root.current = "thermostat"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 30

        Label:
            text: 'THERMOSTAT'

        Slider:
            id: temp_slider
            min: 40
            max: 100
            value: 40
            step: 1

        Label:
            id: slide_val
            text: str(root.temp)

''')


class Thermostat(Screen):
    pass


class Temperature(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

If you want to use the slider's value in your class `Temperature`, simply declare the property in the class:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class Temperature(Screen):
    temp = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Temperature, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

---

[image]